# RSpec controller test makes request into wrong URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this RSpec test:

```
# /spec/controllers/user/builder_tab/biographies_controller_spec.rb
describe User::BuilderTab::BiographiesController do
  before(:each) do
    @user    = create :user 
    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "#update" do
    it "can update" do
      patch :update, profile: { name: "Joe Peshi" }

      expect(User.first.profile.name).to eq "Joe Peshi"
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run it - for some reason it makes this request:

```
No route matches {:profile=>{:name=>"Joe Peshi"}, :controller=>"user/biographies", :action=>"update"}
```

Which obviously fails because the path is not `/user/biographies` - it's `/user/builder_tab/biographies`.

How do I fix it?

My routes are:

```
namespace :user do
  namespace :builder_tab do
    resource :biography, only: [:edit, :update]
  end
end
```

Builder_tab is defined like so:

```
class User::BuilderTab < User
end
```

Comment: are you running on spork?

Comment: how have you defined `BiographiesController`??

Comment: how did you solve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

try to be verbose with your modules and see if it helps

```
module User
  module BuilderTab
    describe BiographiesController
      ..
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: User is not a module (TypeError)